# Purpose of verifying digital signature of a mirrored download link

Tags: digital-signature, checksum, verify

I've done a fair bit of reading about digital signatures but I can't for the life of me work out why I'd need to verify the signature of a digitally signed file uploaded on a mirror site.

The question popped up when I tried to install Maven:
https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

The site urges you to "verify the signature of the release bundles against the public KEYS used by the Apache Maven developers".

I understand the need for integrity which a checksum provides (granted MD5 is considered weak) - why do I need to do more? I know the file that I've downloaded has not been modified since the checksum was initially generated.

Digital signatures are supposed to provide integrity, authenticity and non-repudiation.

1) Integrity is already provided anyway by confirming the checksum.

2) Authenticity - verifies identity of signer. In this case, the signer is the owner of the public key (supposedly a maven developer). In this scenario, do I really care who signed the file?

3) Non-repudiation - Do I really care that the developer can't deny the file was signed by him/her? Maybe if the maven developer created a malicious file and I wanted to sue them for distributing it...

I don't see the significance of authenticity here. I KNOW the sender (eg. someMirrorSite.com) is not the one who signed the file since if I use their public key to try verify the signature, it would be invalid. If I use the maven developer's public key all I'm verifying is the fact that the maven developer signed the file (granted they have a valid certificate which links that maven developer with their public key).

So basically the question is: Provided that I trust maven.apache.org, why should I verify the signature of the file hosted by the mirror site when I can just simply verify the checksum of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Is basically a perspective, do I care who made or compiled a file? Who is behind this so called signed document/file/byte array?

Behind a signed file is Private Key Infrastructure, is like having a notarized document when a particular risky transaction is on play and a bunch of lawyers around, why should I care? Well it depends how important that activity is for you or a third party. Let's say You want to sell a company (small business). This is risky, may be not for you but for the third party, he will make sure there is a notary present to witness the transaction and the state he is receiving the company. At this point it becomes clear to you that you also need a notarized document of you selling the company. Who knows what's going to happen next? May be you don't care what happns next, as long as it's sold, so no notarized document (aka digitally signed document).

Check Integrity = Just lawyers

Digitally Signed Document = You don't trust lawyers that much so you need a notary (who is basically a lawyer anyway :-))

Comment: So by your analogy, the only real reason I'd check the digital signature of the file instead of just checking the checksum is so that I'd be able to hold the developer of the file responsible in case something was wrong with it?

Comment: @Edward Zhou Well not exactly, maybe the responsibility lies with whoever is distributing the file and You. The actual owner can just say the file is distributed under [whatever rights] and it is your responsibility to check if a file in a mirrored site is exactly the same as the original that he has. This ofcourse will be in the event that by your actions in using the file in question incurred in a seriours liability to a third party by your omission to verify the checksum and the signature on the file

Answer (score 0):

If there is a file `F`, and `C = checksum(F)`, then when you download `F` you can recompute `C` and see if it matches the published value.  But, how do you know if this published value of `C` can be trusted? If I am "Evil Inc." I can make a compromised copy of `F`, call it `Fe` and then compute its checksum `Ce`, and publish both on my website.  Many people will not bother to even look at the checksum, but even those that do will be fooled, because they will compute `Ce` too.

Using a Public Key signature as the checksum is an attempt to strengthen this procedure.

Comment: The thing is, I trust maven.apache.org - what I don't necessarily trust is the mirrored link of the download which is hosted on some other site. mave.apache.org has published C = checksum(F). I'm downloading a file from an untrusted site, Fe. I can compute checksum(Fe) and compare that to C (which comes from the site that I trust). A digital signature in this scenario adds nothing to the integrity of the file.

Comment: Your level of diligence is, then, considerably above the norm. In my opinion, to be successful, the method of protection needs to be automateable -- a tool (maybe even web browsers) can download `F` and also grab `S` (sig for F) and warn the user if there is a mismatch.